# Dash in offline mode without internet . show loding.. only with no graphs shown

Tags: plotly, dashboard, plotly-dash

I don’t see any plot in page just loading and no graphs is shown
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jt9wB.png)

my python version is :Anaconda 3 Python 3.6.4
my server :centos7 with no internet access

First I installed dash all sources and python *setup.py* install all of them

```
install dash 0.22.0 
install dash-renderer 0.13.0 
install dash-html-components 0.11.0 
install dash-core-components 0.26.0 
install plotly the latest version
```

I try to open page with many browser like Chrome and Firefox and Internet Explorer but still show loading.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.offline as offline
import plotly.graph_objs as go


app = dash.Dash()
app.css.config.serve_locally = True
app.scripts.config.serve_locally = True
app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),

    html.Div(children='''
        Dash: A web application framework for Python.
    '''),

    dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        figure={
            'data': [
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 1, 2], 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'SF'},
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [2, 4, 5], 'type': 'bar', 'name': u'Montréal'},
            ],
            'layout': {
                'title': 'Dash Data Visualization'
            }
        }
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run_server(debug=True,host = '0.0.0.0',port=5001)
```

i retry to do assets folder and put
custom-script.js header.css typography.css

put still not show anything just loading…

[inspect element Network Monitor image png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jz7dr.png)
[without assets folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewNXU.png)
How can I resolve this issue?

[link for the issue in dash form i open](https://community.plot.ly/t/dash-in-offline-mode-without-internet-show-loding-only-with-no-graphs/12269?u=mrmagdy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you i already solve it by uninstall dash-renderer 0.13.0 and install it again i realized that when i open monitor network ther is no GET for dash-layout or dash-dependencies so i try to uninstall dash-renderer 0.13.0 and install it again and its work now thank you

Answer (score 2):

By default plotly dash uses CDNs to serve some files.

To use it offline you have to specify that in your code.

Minimal example:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash()

# Serve files locally
app.css.config.serve_locally = True
app.scripts.config.serve_locally = True

app.layout = html.Div(
    [ html.H1("This is a test")]
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: i do that already but still same problem   the page give me loading...  after i put app.css.config.serve_locally = True
app.scripts.config.serve_locally = True

Comment: The please add a minimal example.

Comment: yes itry the example code you put and still same result  for loading..   i attached  the code i test  and all ways that i try to do

Comment: What are the Network Monitor in Chrome showing? Does it try to load external resources or show some error?

Comment: i attached the png for network nmonitor 1 for loading from assets folder and another for without assets folder

Comment: This solves my problem -- running dash inside corporate network

Answer (score 0):

thank you i already solve it by uninstall dash-renderer 0.13.0 and install it again i realized that  when i open monitor  network  ther is no GET for  dash-layout or dash-dependencies so i try to uninstall dash-renderer 0.13.0 and install it again and its work now

[image]